# Radio button inside table

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, input, radio-button, html-table

I have a group of radio button that I put inside table, the code is like this:

```
<table class="table table-responsive">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Courier</th>
            <th>Service</th>
        </tr>
     </thead>
     <tbody>
        <form>
        <tr>
            <td>
                 <div class="radio">
                      <label><input type="radio" name="optradio">TIKI</label>
                 </div>
            </td>
            <td>
                  Regular Shipping
            </td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
             <td>
                 <div class="radio">
                      <label><input type="radio" name="optradio">JNE</label>
                 </div>
             </td>
             <td>
                  Express Shipping
             </td>
         </tr>
         </form>
     </tbody>
 </table>
```

When I click on one of Courier cell for example JNE, the button is selected, now I want to the button is selected too when I click on Express Shipping, how can I make it ? and the vertical align of Service column doesn't have same high as Courier column, how to fix it ? I using bootstrap.

Comment: Do you need a check box instead?

Comment: @ManojKumar - I think when you read that first sentence again he is asking how he can click "Express Shipping" and it select the radio box for express shipping. This is how I read it mainly because a checkbox for 2 types of shipping doesn't sound right.

Comment: face-palm :( you have a valid point @Jesse

Comment: I had to read it twice myself lol. My answer below should help

Comment: @Jesse deleting my answer, but you can add the bootstrap css and resolve that align issue too `vertical align of Service column doesn't have same high as Courier column` when you add the bootstrap css you will see text not align.

Comment: @Shehary I'm on my mobile now going to sleep. Feel free to edit mine and include the bootstrap stuff if you like. You can always edit your answer as well

Answer (score 22, accepted):

This can be accomplished using [label for](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/label)

See the following code and run the snippet below ::

```html
<table class="table table-responsive">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Courier</th>
            <th>Service</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    
    <tbody>
        <form>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <div class="radio">
                        <label><input type="radio" id='regular' name="optradio">TIKI</label>
                    </div>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <div class="radiotext">
                        <label for='regular'>Regular Shipping</label>
                    </div>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <div class="radio">
                        <label><input type="radio" id='express' name="optradio">JNE</label>
                    </div>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <div class="radiotext">
                        <label for='express'>Express Shipping</label>
                    </div>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </form>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

As you can see you are now able to click Express Shipping and Regular Shipping to select the radio buttons as requested.

Comment: Thank you guys, nice collaboration of you both :) ... its working perfectly :)

Comment: I am just wondering if the form tags should be outside the table. I am not sure if it is right to put the tags inside the table for correct markup, although I could be wrong.

Comment: @ThomasWilliams The form tags should definitely be somewhere else then inside the tbody but causes no issues doing so. This was originally a modification of the original questions code. If it was my code, I would likely place the form tag before the table in this specific code block.

Comment: Yes that is what I normally do. Thanks I just wondered if it might cause problems down the line.

Answer (score 12):

You can use jQuery so the entire `row` is then able to be selected, not just the input or label separately. See example.

```js
$('.table tbody tr').click(function(event) {
  if (event.target.type !== 'radio') {
    $(':radio', this).trigger('click');
  }
});
```

```css
.table-responsive tbody tr {
  cursor: pointer;
}
.table-responsive .table thead tr th {
  padding-top: 15px;
  padding-bottom: 15px;
}
.table-responsive .table tbody tr td {
  padding-top: 15px;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="table-responsive">
  <table class="table table-hover">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Courier</th>
        <th>Service</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <input type="radio" name="radios" id="radio1" />
          <label for="radio1">TIKI</label>
        </td>
        <td>Regular Shipping</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <input type="radio" name="radios" id="radio2" />
          <label for="radio2">JNE</label>
        </td>
        <td>Express Shipping</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this Code to fixed the issue

```
 $('.table tbody tr td').click(function (event) {
        if (event.target.type !== 'radio') {
            $(':radio', this).trigger('click');
        }
    });
```